# Telegraf config file - substrings and converting hexadecimal to int for ingestion

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I have incoming BLE beacon data from a gateway in the following format:

```
{"msg":"advData","gmac":"94A408B02508","obj":
[
    {"type":32,"dmac":"AC233FE0784F","data1":"0201060303F1FF1716E2C56DB5DFFB48D2B060D0F5A71096E000000000C564","rssi":-45,"time":"2022-10-13 02:46:24"},
    {"type":32,"dmac":"AC233FE078A1","data1":"0201060303F1FF1716E2C56DB5DFFB48D2B060D0F5A71096E000000000C564","rssi":-42,"time":"2022-10-13 02:46:26"}
]
```

}

and I want to extract the attributes *gmac*, *dmac*, *rssi*, and process attribute *data1* and ingest these into influxdb via a telegraf config file.

I can successfully ingest *gmac*, *dmac*, and *rssi* using the below telegraf config:

```
  ## Data format to consume.
  ## Each data format has its own unique set of configuration options, read
  ## more about them here:
  ## https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_INPUT.md
  data_format = "json_v2"
  tagexclude = ["topic"]
  [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2]]
    measurement_name = "a"
    timestamp_path = "obj.#.time"
    timestamp_format = "unix"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.tag]]
        path = "gmac"
        rename = "g"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.tag]]
        path = "obj.#.dmac"
        rename = "d"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.field]]
        path = "obj.#.rssi"
        type = "int"
        rename = "r"
```

However, I'm not sure how to process the *data1* attribute where I need to (1) extract characters 15 and 16 and convert this from a hexadecimal value to an integer, and (2) extract characters 13 and 14 and convert each hexadecimal value to an integer before combining them together as a float (character 13 is the whole number component, character 14 is the decimal component).

Can anybody provide some guidance here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Got it working thanks to some help over at [Influx Community](https://community.influxdata.com/t/telegraf-config-getting-substrings-and-converting-hexadecimal-to-int/27014/2), I've pasted the relevant section of the telegraf config file if this is of help to anyone else:

```html
data_format = "json_v2"
  tagexclude = ["topic"]
  [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2]]
    measurement_name = "a"
    timestamp_path = "obj.#.time"
    timestamp_format = "unix"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.tag]]
        path = "gmac"
        # g is gateway MAC address
        rename = "g"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.tag]]
        path = "obj.#.dmac"
        # d is beacon MAC address
        rename = "d"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.field]]
        path = "obj.#.rssi"
        type = "int"
        # r is RSSI of beacon
        rename = "r"
    [[inputs.mqtt_consumer.json_v2.field]]
        path = "obj.#.data1"
        data_type = "string"

  [[processors.starlark]]
    namepass = ["a"]
    source = '''
def apply(metric):
    data1 = metric.fields.pop("data1")
    tempWhole = int("0x" + data1[26:28], 0)
    tempDecimal = int("0x" + data1[28:30], 0)
    tempDecimal = tempDecimal / 100
    # t is temperature of chip to two decimal points precision
    metric.fields["t"] = tempWhole + tempDecimal
    # b is battery level in mV
    metric.fields["b"] = int("0x" + data1[30:34], 0)

    return metric

'''
```